# A game where you program a robot to fulfill missions

Tags: commodore-64, identify-this-game, cpc

I'm looking for a game. Unfortunately there're only few things I remember:

- You had a robot. There was no way to steer it manually, so to solve a room, every step to do had to be programmed in advance
- It was isometric 3D (similar to e.g. 'batman', looks like [this](http://www.gamesetwatch.com/2009/06/way_cute_batman_remake.php))
- It was for a 8-bit computer, most probably C64 or CPC

I know this is very little info; perhaps someone can recall it.

Comment: The original is "Karel The Robot": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karel_(programming_language)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are probably referring to the 1984 release of [Chipwits](https://www.mobygames.com/game/macintosh/chipwits). It was originally released for the Macintosh, and was ported to the Apple ][ and Commodore 64.

The screenshot below is from the version for the C64.

Interestingly, [a modern version](https://playchipwits.com/) of the game exists too.

[image: C64 ChipWits]

Comment: In Chipwits your robot needed pie and coffee.

Comment: Seems to be Chipwits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChipWits) also see https://web.archive.org/web/20120206061135/http://www.breueronline.de/klaus/chipwits/ and http://www.lemon64.com/?mainurl=http%3A//www.lemon64.com/games/details.php%3FID%3D3797

Comment: Oh, is this the predecessor for Chip's Challenge?

Comment: There is a ChipWits revival. https://playchipwits.com/2020/10/22/welcome-to-chipwits/ as well as a ChipWits Pioneers board on Discord.

Answer (score 6):

Was it [Robot Odyssey](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/bitwise/2014/01/robot_odyssey_the_hardest_computer_game_of_all_time.html)? This fulfills most of the criteria in your question except that Robot Odyssey was not isometric - or at least I have never seen an isometric version. It required you to program a robot in advance to solve room challenges and it was an 8-bit game in the 8-bit era.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFU3l1Vh7cQ) a video of the game on the Apple //.

Comment: no, it wasn't. but it looks pretty interesting, I will have a look :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you mean **Paradroid**. This game was originally written for the Commodore C64 and published through  *Hewson Consultants*. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEam-zQgWcU).

The game was (at least on the C64) not isometric, but rather had a somewhat 3D-enhanced birds-eye view and had you program robots to regain control over an alien-infected spaceship.

The game was ported to a number of other micros, like the Amiga and the Atari ST.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradroid) has an article on the game, and the game itself was so popular that there even is a relatively modern, free 3D enhanced version today entirely done by fans: [Freedroid](http://www.freedroid.org/).

Comment: If Paradroid is almost the answer then probably he's actually thinking of Quazatron. It's the Spectrum port of Paradroid, except that the authors switched it to isometric as a better fit to the target architecture.

Comment: Quazatron, for the record: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeIbvankrPI

Comment: Yep, Quazatron was similar, or, rather, a "port" to the Spectrum, as you say - Distributed by the same publisher.

Comment: "There was no way to steer it manually, so to solve a room, every step to do had to be programmed in advance" doesn't sound anything like Paradroid or Quazatron to me.

Comment: Definitely not Paradroid - in Paradroid you directly controlled the robot with the keyboard.

Comment: No, you directly controlled the robot with the joystick.

Answer (score 0):

Origin systems created a game called Omega.
[Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_(video_game))

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing. Please include some more information (gameplay, screenshots etc.) so that it is easier for the OP to verify whether this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I was after a very similar game and just came across it again.

Mission Omega - C64 and Amstrad?

I'd recommend you check it out but you build robots from parts and send them out to explore. Choosing everything from their mode of movement to their weapons and sensors.